# C# Backgroundworker ReportProgress() not executing

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker, reportprogress

Hello I am trying to populate a progress bar but the ReportProgress call its not been executed for some reason.

Here is my code

```
    //create status_Worker
    status_Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    status_Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Status_DoWork);
    status_Worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Worker_ProgressChanged);
    status_Worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    status_Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

    private void Status_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //make call to Logger class getStatus method
        _logger.getStatus(sender);
    }

    private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            return;
        } 
        else
        {
            Start_button.IsEnabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void Start_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //initiate status_Worker when button is clicked
        status_Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        Start_button.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Now inside the Logger class I have the getStatus() method. i make a call to a local server to get status of the files been processed and all that works and I see the values been updated automatically on my MainWindow.Status.

```
    public async Task getStatus(object sender)
    {
        BackgroundWorker statusWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        //Making a call to ReportProgress here works and it shows the progress bar
        //statusWorker.ReportProgress(99);

        //REQUEST STATUS from a server
        //Status format
        //CurrentParser, NumberOfFilesToParse,CountOfCompletedFiles,Status, NumberOfProcessRunning
        int CountOfCompletedFiles;
        int NumberOfFilesToParse;
        int percent;
        string status = "Running";
        string[] stats;
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

        while(status!="Complete")
        {

            var getstatus = await request.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:8085/status");
            logs.Add(getstatus);
            stats = getstatus.Split(delimiterChars);
            NumberOfFilesToParse = Int32.Parse(stats[1]);
            CountOfCompletedFiles = Int32.Parse(stats[2]);
            status = stats[3];

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            MainWindow.main.Status = "Files to process: " + NumberOfFilesToParse + " Files completed: " + CountOfCompletedFiles + " Status: " + status;

            if(NumberOfFilesToParse!=0 && status!="Complete")
            {
                percent = (CountOfCompletedFiles * 100) / NumberOfFilesToParse;
                //a call to ReportProgress here stalls the program at this point
                //statusWorker.ReportProgress(percent);
            }

        }
        MainWindow.main.Status = "Completed!";

    }
```

A call to ReportProgress at the start of the getStatus method works but a call to ReportProgress during or after my while loop results in process stalling at that point. Even when using static numbers ReportProgress(99) it only executes at the beginning

Comment: You're on a different thread. Also calling `Thread.Sleep` defeats the purpose of async operations and will stall. You shouldn't be passing in the background worker at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Status_DoWork` method is doing fire-and-forget. It's calling an `async Task` method and then ignoring the `Task` it returns.

One of the problems you've run into is that [`BackgroundWorker` simply doesn't work with `async`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html). What's actually happening is that as soon as the first `await` is reached in `getStatus`, it [returns an incomplete `Task`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) to `Status_DoWork`, which then exits. This causes the `BackgroundWorker` to finish, so raising progress events no longer makes sense for that `BackgroundWorker`.

[The modern replacement for `BackgroundWorker` is `Task.Run`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html), which [includes support for progress reporting](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html). Ideally, you would only [use `Task.Run` for CPU-bound methods, not the I/O-bound methods](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html):

```
private void Start_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Start_button.IsEnabled = false;
  var progress = new Progress<int>(update => progressbar1.Value = update);
  try
  {
    await _logger.getStatus(progress);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    Start_button.IsEnabled = true;
  }
}

public async Task getStatus(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  int CountOfCompletedFiles;
  int NumberOfFilesToParse;
  int percent;
  string status = "Running";
  string[] stats;
  char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

  while(status!="Complete")
  {
    var getstatus = await request.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:8085/status");
    logs.Add(getstatus);
    stats = getstatus.Split(delimiterChars);
    NumberOfFilesToParse = Int32.Parse(stats[1]);
    CountOfCompletedFiles = Int32.Parse(stats[2]);
    status = stats[3];

    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)); // process file in Task.Run
    MainWindow.main.Status = "Files to process: " + NumberOfFilesToParse + " Files completed: " + CountOfCompletedFiles + " Status: " + status;

    if(NumberOfFilesToParse!=0 && status!="Complete")
    {
      percent = (CountOfCompletedFiles * 100) / NumberOfFilesToParse;
      progress.Report(percent);
    }
  }
  MainWindow.main.Status = "Completed!";
}
```

Comment: Thank You! this worked. Only thing i had to create a new method in main called "public async Task startStatus()" because the "await _logger.getStatus(progress)" requires an async method